# Filter certain wavelengths of visible light in an image

Tags: image, image-processing, filter

Given the wavelength range of visible light ~380nm-720nm, is there a way an image can be processed as if it went through a filter where I am blocking out certain parts of this range? I am looking for something similar to this:
https://metamaterial.com/laser-filter-comparison-tool/?submissionGuid=c2a5b105-c4c3-4c7a

Comment: DSP/physics/physiology question. -- look up the sensitivity curves of human cone cells, which is _the model_ everyone tries to match. the red cones have a second minor peak near violet/UV, which causes our perception to be circular (color wheel), rather than linear like the wavelengths are really arranged. -- if you have those curves, you could __approximately__ reconstruct the input spectrum... __very coarsely__

Comment: related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/51870/can-red-cone-cells-actually-see-much-red-light